# Underscore in fbox

Tags: characters

How can I write the character `_` in an `\fbox`?

```
\fbox{PART one_Part two}
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\_` or `\textunderscore`. The problem is that, on its own, `_` is a reserved LaTeX character like `%` and that is why you are getting the error. The fact that it is inside a `fbox` should not be the issue. For a complete list of reserved characters see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#Reserved_Characters.